# Transform: Image {file} cannot be found with

Tags: image-transforms

Why do i get an error

*throw new Exception(Craft::t('Image “{file}” cannot be found.', array('file' => $file->filename)));*

for

```
{% set myImage = entry.pr_foto.first %}
{% set params = { width: 300, height: 200 } %}
<img  src="{{ myImage.getUrl(params) }}" height="{{ myImage.getHeight(params) }}" width="{{ myImage.getWidth(params) }}" alt="">
```

while

```
{% set myImage = entry.pr_foto.first %}
<img src="{{ myImage.url }}">
```

shows the image?

The filesystem path for photos is uploads/photos/. The upload works fine in the admin. It's only the transform.

Full trace error:
[image]

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: - your source image might be missing in this environement.

- your image path might be wrong.

- your image transform might be missing and craft thinks the transform has already been made. (if thats the case empty the table 'craft_assettransformindex' so all transforms will be recreated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i was working on a localised website I had to use the full path,
in my case on MAMP PRO that was:
/Users/davedriesmans/Documents/Sites/website.dev/public/uploads/photos/

guess i'll have to change then when going into production

use environmentVariables like Mats Mikkel Rummelhoff suggests

Comment: You can use [environmentVariables](https://craftcms.com/docs/multi-environment-configs#example-multi-environment-asset-source-settings) for Asset source paths - that way you won't have to change them every time you sync the databases between environments.